# Detect whether an expression could have an undefined result

Tags: javascript, math, expression, undefined

I would like to determine whether a given expression can have an undefined result.

For instance, take the following computation:

```
a = rand() * 1000  // a real number >=0 and <1000
b = trunc( a )*2   // an even number between 0 and 1998
c = sin( a )       // a real number >=-1 and <=1
d = pow( c, b )    // a positive real number >=0 and <=1
e = log( a )       // either undefined (-Infinity), or a real number <6.907…
f = sqrt( e )      // either undefined, or a real number >=0 and <2.628…
```

How can I write a program that tells me that `e` and `f` can be undefined, while the others are always defined?

Is there any library that can check this for me?

I'm currently writing in JavaScript, but I'm willing to change language if there's no such library for JS, but it's there for other languages.

Comment: I doubt there's a general method for this.

Comment: @Barmar do you think it's impossible or what issues do you see?

Comment: Your examples are wrong. For instance `log(0)` is not defined either

Comment: You could possibly do it by writing type descriptions for every function. But that won't extend to user-defined functions.

Comment: @derpirscher: you're right. I fixed the example.

Comment: @Barmar: that's OK. It's enough to have it for a small set of "standard" mathematical functions. (Once that exist, it would automatically extend to those user-defined functions that are expressed as a composition of standard ones, right?)

Comment: If you have a defined set of mathematical operations, you can probably draw some conclusions, based on the mathematical properties (especialy domain and range) of that function. Ie, for instance `sqrt(x)` is only defined for `x >= 0` or `log(x)` is only defined for `x > 0`. But I doubt there is an (easy) way

Comment: @derpirscher: yes, for `sqrt(x)` is pretty easy and it's enough to use interval analysis/interval arithmetics. But for something like `pow(-1, y)` it's more difficult I need to know whether `y` must be 0 or a positive even number. Interval analysis isn't enough for that. I'm wondering how I can implement a solution, or preferably if there's an implementation already available.

Comment: This is probably better suited at https://math.stackexchange.com. Because once you know it's theoretically possible, implementing it might be (more or less) straightforward. If the math guys say it's not possible, there is no point trying to do it.

Comment: `d = pow( c, b )    // a positive real number >=0 and <=1` That's not correct. `c` can be negative, and `b` is not necessarily an integer. For instance, how do you define `pow(-0.5, 0.5)`?

Comment: @derpirscher I believe it should be possible (I can't be sure of course), but the main challenge I see is to choose how to represent on a computer the set of possible values a symbol can have. The board you linked might be more appropriate never the less. I'll try to ask there.

Comment: @Stef: woops! I meant to define `b = trunc(a)*2`. Fixing it.

Comment: In python there is module sympy which kinda does this: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/calculus/index.html#sympy.calculus.util.continuous_domain

Comment: @Stef: thanks, it seems very similar to what I'm looking for. However it seems unable to detect that `pow(-1, x)` can be undefined. `continuous_domain(pow(-1, x), x, S.Reals)` returns all of R.

Comment: @BlueNebula I'm afraid python returns complex numbers for `pow(-1, negative_number)`, so it doesn't consider it to be undefined.

Comment: @Stef sure, but it says that the domain is R, not C.

Comment: @BlueNebula Although `continuous_domain(2 ** floor(a), a, Interval(0, 10))` does return `Interval(0, 10)`, as if it didn't notice the discontinuities...

Comment: @BlueNebula The **domain** is R. The **range** is C.

Comment: @Stef I understand now, thanks. I have a lot of confusion in my mind, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Using python and its library sympy, there is [sympy.calculus.util.continuous_domain](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/calculus/index.html#sympy.calculus.util.continuous_domain).

```py
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import sin, log, sqrt
from sympy.sets import Interval
from sympy.calculus.util import continuous_domain, function_range


a = Symbol('a')
b = 3

c = sin(a)
d = c ** b
e = log(a)
f = sqrt(e)

for y in (c,d,e,f):
    print(y)
    print('domain: ', continuous_domain(y, a, Interval(0,1000)))
    print('range:  ', function_range(y, a, Interval(0,1000)))
    print()
```

Output:

```py
sin(a)
domain:  Interval(0, 1000)
range:   Interval(-1, 1)

sin(a)**3
domain:  Interval(0, 1000)
range:   Interval(-1, 1)

log(a)
domain:  Interval.Lopen(0, 1000)
range:   Interval(-oo, log(1000))

sqrt(log(a))
domain:  Interval(1, 1000)
range:   Interval(0, sqrt(log(1000)))
```

Unfortunately, replacing `b = 3` with `b = Symbol('b', integer = True)` or `b = floor(a)` both result in a spectacular crash of `function_range(d, a, Interval(0,1000))`. You can still get the `continuous_domain`, but not the `function_range`.

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer as it's very close to what I was wishing for. I'll try to play with sympy and see if it matches my needs before accepting the answer.